# How I can display datas on my screen swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display employee names, salaries, ages on the screen but it gives me "Initializer 'init(_:rowContent:)' requires that 'EmployeeData' conform to 'Identifiable'"  error and "Undefined variable" error. How I can fix these and display datas. Thank u

```
struct EmployeeData: Codable {
    var data: [Employee]
    var status: String
}

struct Employee: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var employee_name: String
    var employee_salary: String
    var employee_age: String
}

class FetchToDo: ObservableObject {

    @Published var todos = [EmployeeData]()
    func getData(completion: @escaping (EmployeeData) -> ()){

        let url = URL(string: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(EmployeeData.self, from: todoData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        completion(decodedData)
                    }

                    print(decodedData)
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()

    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    // 1.
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchToDo()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // 2.
            List(fetch.todos) { todo in
                VStack{
                    // 3.
                    Text("Hello")
                    Text("he")
                    Text("Eh")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the error message one more time and ask yourself if EmployeeData conforms to Identifiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this code, so let's look fix them step by step.

**Step 1 - Fix build error**

Your observed object is an array of `EmployeeData` which does not conform to the `Identifiable` protocol. This is an easy fix. In your FetchToDo class replace:

```
@Published var todos = [EmployeeData]()
```

with

```
@Published var todos = [Employee]()
```

Now the project builds, although the list is empty in the Preview and when you run it on the device.

**Step 2 - Fetch the data**

You need to observe your data source and then populate the list from the published `employees` property. It helps if the view actually loads the fetched data rather than static strings. And when the view appears, you can call the `getData()` function of the data source.

That isn't enough, because you need to create an exception to App Transport Security in your Info.plist file like this:

[image]

If you rewrite your code like this, it will work in the simulator.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct EmployeeData: Codable {
    var data: [Employee]
    var status: String
}

struct Employee: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var employee_name: String
    var employee_salary: String
    var employee_age: String
}

class EmployeeDataSource: ObservableObject {

    @Published var employees = [Employee]()

    func getData(){

        let url = URL(string: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let todoData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(EmployeeData.self, from: todoData)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async{
                        self.employees = decodedData.data
                    }

                    print(decodedData)
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataSource = EmployeeDataSource()

    var body: some View {
        List(dataSource.employees) { employee in
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(employee.employee_name)
                Text(employee.employee_salary)
            }
        }.onAppear { self.dataSource.getData() }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

You need to run your preview to see it working there. You can work around this with a bit more rewriting of your code but that's a much bigger question.

Comment: thank u very much. It worked except info. changes. I did same setting first as u shown above, it printed " No Data" but I changed as " Load Arbitrary - YES " then It worked well. thank you very much again ❤️